# преобразовать выражение с помощью sympy: проверить правильность введённого символьного выражения, принимая предыдущее истиной

Tags: python, sympy

Дана строка:  знак1

Юзер вводит: 1/ #знак1# 1/

Например, пользователь вводит `a>b` и потом `1/a < 1/b` то питон говорит что все правильно (`#знак1#` означает знак наоборот).

Comment: Приведите пример строки введенной пользователем и ожидаемый результат...  `#знак1#` - что это обозначает?

Comment: например пользователь вводит a>b и потом 1/a < 1/b то питон говорит что все правильно (#знак1# означает знак наоборот)

Comment: и что вы ожидаете увидеть в результате?

Comment: правильное ли выражение или нет

Comment: не уверен что это можно сделать...

Comment: `ask(Q.is_true(1/a < 1/b), Q.is_true(a > b))` но [это ещё не реализовано](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html)